# Clean interface builder compilation

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I want to use IBDesignable and IBInspectable to display some custom views. Everything worked fine until it I made some errors. I fixed them but the Interface builder still renders an old state of the view. My guess is that it is using some old files. Is there any way to clean or clear derived data for Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

**Shift-Command-K** to clean and **Option-Shift-Command-K** to clear data

They are under the product menu dropdown if you prefer the mouse.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/MenuCommands/MenuCommands014.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH2-SW16